# Not all code paths return a value in Typescript Promise

Tags: promise, typescript2.0

I have a method that returns a Typescript promise. I am tightening up my code by enabling TSLint and it says that "Not all code paths return a value" for this method.

Please critique my code - I cannot work out what path it is referring to:

```
public getExtendedProfile(): Promise<any> {
        //only do this if they are authenticated
        if (this.authenticated()) {
            if (typeof this.userProfile.user_id !== 'undefined') {
                if (typeof this.user == 'undefined') {                    
                    this.profileService.getExtendedUserProfile(this.userProfile.user_id)
                        .then(data => {
                            return Promise.resolve(data);
                        })
                        .catch((error: any) => {
                            return Promise.reject(error)
                        });
                }
                else {
                    return Promise.resolve(this.user);
                }
            }
            else {
                return Promise.reject("No user stored");
            }
        }
        else {
            return Promise.reject("Not Authenticated");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this.profileService. ...` -> `return this.profileService. ...`

Comment: Thanks, this is working now

Comment: That code is really messy, and `.catch` with a same reject is bad. You could rewrite it as: https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/4bc9905a4571e95edcda3979b658a7c9 which does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - yes, I was not happy with this code - it kind of morphed into a monster due to my inexperience with Promises. I'll refactor

Answer (score 0):

```js
// una alternativa podria ser
:Promise<any>

// cambiar a
:Promise<any|void>
```

docs typescript funciones: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html